# Interface & StringLog Confusion

Tags: java, arrays, string, interface

I am reading the book Object Oriented Data Structures using Java and I'm in chapter 2. I decided to try out one of the exercises they had in there but the code does not seem to work for me even though they came straight from the book. Can anybody clarify this?

```
package chapter2;

public interface StringLogInterface
{
    void insert(String element);
    boolean isFull();
    int size();
    boolean contains(String element);
    void clear();
    String getName();
    String toString();
}
```

This project uses three files, I'm posting the remaining two below.

```
package chapter2;

public class ArrayStringLog
{
  protected String name;              
  protected String[] log;             
  protected int lastIndex = -1;       

  public ArrayStringLog(String name, int maxSize)
  {
    log = new String[maxSize];
    this.name = name;
  }

  public ArrayStringLog(String name) 
  {
    log = new String[100];
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void insert(String element)
  {      
    lastIndex++;
    log[lastIndex] = element;
  }

  public boolean isFull()
  {              
    if (lastIndex == (log.length - 1)) 
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public int size()
  {
    return (lastIndex + 1);
  }

  public boolean contains(String element)
  {                 
    int location = 0;
    while (location <= lastIndex) 
    {
      if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(log[location]))  // if they match
        return true;
      else
        location++;
    }
   return false;
  }

  public void clear()
  {                  
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
      log[i] = null;
    lastIndex = -1;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    String logString = "Log: " + name + "\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++)
      logString = logString + (i+1) + ". " + log[i] + "\n";

    return logString;
  }
}
```

Last part:

```
package chapter2;

public class UseStringLog
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
    StringLogInterface sample;
    sample = new ArrayStringLog("Example Use");
    sample.insert("Elvis");
    sample.insert("King Louis XII");
    sample.insert("Captain Kirk");
    System.out.println(sample);
    System.out.println("The size of the log is " + sample.size());
    System.out.println("Elvis is in the log: " + sample.contains("Elvis"));
    System.out.println("Santa is in the log: " + sample.contains("Santa"));
    }
}
```

This last part is what got me confused. On the line,

```
sample = new ArrayStringLog("Example Use");
```

NetBeans says "incomparable types, required: StringLogInterface, found: ArrayStringLog.

They all build successfully, but shouldn't the last file with the three println statements at the end print something out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make  `ArrayStringLog` implement `StringLogInterface`.

```
public class ArrayStringLog implements StringLogInterface {
  // ...
}
```

Only then is this possible:

```
StringLogInterface sample;
sample = new ArrayStringLog("Example Use");
```

Comment: That got rid of the error but it still doesn't give me those three println statements when I run it?